# How to communicate between the parent and child process in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, popen

I have a main program in python that starts some workers and submits some jobs to them. Here is a basic pseudo-code of the `worker.py` :

```
possibly_long_init()
print "initialization finished"
while True:
   print "The worker is ready"
   listen_for_incoming_work()
```

The main program spawns the worker process by using the Python's subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'python worker.py'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

In the main program, I would like to know when the worker is "ready" for work. How can I know in `main.py` that `worker.py` child process has been initialized and it is ready to accept tasks.

Comment: Any reason you can't use the multiprocessing-Module? This will allow for this kind of information exchange in simple pythonic ways.

Comment: Agree with @deets on this. Depending on the type of work (I/O bound or not), you can leverage the `queue`, `multithreading` or `multiprocessing` modules. If not mistaken, the latter has a native `queue` within.

Comment: Thanks, yes multiprocessing library has a better interface.